# Dictionary value to column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary like this

`{'error': {'userInfo': {}, 'code': 'sdf', 'requestId': 'dsfsdf', 'domain': 'sdgsdgf', 'message': "Hello", 'staticCode': '0'}}`

Inside of a dataframe like this

```
    City    error
6   ABC {'error': {'userInfo': {}, 'code': 'sdf', '...
```

And I want to have a new column with the message that appears in the dict so that the final result will be

```
    City    error                                        message
6   ABC {'error': {'userInfo': {}, 'code': 'sdf', '...   Hello
```

Can you please help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Define the path of the `dict` column as a new column, it should work:

```
data = {'City':'ABC','error':{'error': {'userInfo': {}, 'code': 'sdf', 'requestId': 'dsfsdf', 'domain': 'sdgsdgf', 'message': "Hello", 'staticCode': '0'}}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['message'] = df['error']['error']['message']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      City                                              error message
error  ABC  {'userInfo': {}, 'code': 'sdf', 'requestId': '...   Hello
```

### Edit:

If dealing with mutltiple the method above might fail, then I would create a series with a list comprehension:

```
data = {'City':['ABC','CDE'],'error':[{'error': {'userInfo': {}, 'code': 'sdf', 'requestId': 'dsfsdf', 'domain': 'sdgsdgf', 'message': "Hello", 'staticCode': '0'}},{'error': {'userInfo': {}, 'code': 'sdf', 'requestId': 'dsfsdf', 'domain': 'sdgsdgf', 'message': "Goodbye", 'staticCode': '0'}}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['message'] = [i['error']['message'] for i in df['error'].values]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  City                                              error  message
0  ABC  {'error': {'userInfo': {}, 'code': 'sdf', 'req...    Hello
1  CDE  {'error': {'userInfo': {}, 'code': 'sdf', 'req...  Goodbye
```